# How to put an extra row with fixed text between a large list of words in Excel?

Tags: excel, list

Who knows a way of simply pasting a list of words in excel in one column, and then Excel instantly creates the same list next to it, but with an extra row with a fixed text between every original row?

example:

---

**input column:**

- word 1
- word 2
- word 3

... etc.

with the word "beep" as an example of a 'fixed text'.

---

**output column:**

- word 1
- beep
- word 2
- beep
- word 3
- beep
- ... etc.*

---

Screenshot example:
[View example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EURfe.png)

The lists are very long (50.000+ words). I can use lists in this format for a Reminder App that only reads lists that are in the above mentioned format. I have to convert a lot of lists in this way

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you happy using VBA to do this?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?  Where have you run into problems?

Comment: I tried using the 'sort' function in Excel: putting the complete 'input list' in one column, then adding an extra column next to it with numbers that count from 1 to [amount of words in the list], starting at the same row as where the input (word list) starts. Then, in the same column as where the 'input list' is located, i put the 'fixed word' underneath the list, duplicating the word to the same amount of cells as the input list has. In the second column with the counting numbers, I'd start counting from 1 again from the first time the 'fixed word' shows. Then I sort the list of numbers.

Comment: The problem with this workflow was: it's too slow since I have to 'generate' a lot of lists in the above mentioned format. I'd prefer a simple 'paste input list', then excel generates the new list, and then I can simply 'copy output list'.

Comment: @TimWilkinson: Using VBA would be allright if it will get the right results, I understand the basics about it, but i'm not an expert. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple VBA routine, based on your screenshot.  You will obviously need to adjust the ranges to match your real data.  Since VBA arrays are used, it should run much more quickly than solutions involving multiple reads/writes from the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewList()
Dim vInput As Variant, vNewList As Variant
Dim sFixedWord As String
Dim I As Long

vInput = Range("a2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
sFixedWord = Range("b2")

ReDim vNewList(0 To UBound(vInput, 1) * 2, 1 To 1)
vNewList(0, 1) = Range("C1") 'Header
For I = 1 To UBound(vInput, 1)
    vNewList((I - 1) * 2 + 1, 1) = vInput(I, 1)
    vNewList((I - 1) * 2 + 2, 1) = sFixedWord
Next I

With Range("c1").Resize(UBound(vNewList, 1) + 1)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vNewList
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks you so much!! Made my day! One more little question: now I have to press the play button (to run the script) everytime I paste a new list into the 'input list' column. Is there a way of of adding something into the script to let it run automatically everytime I paste a new list? (or change a word in the input list?)

Comment: @user6618868 You could use an event-triggered macro, but I suspect that would trigger too often, depending on exactly what you are doing and how you implement it.  I suggest you set up a short cut key; or put a button on the worksheet, and continue to trigger it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "simplified" version :

```vb
Sub beep()
    Range(Selection.End(xlUp), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select ' optional to select the rest of the words
    values = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Selection)
    Text = Join(values, vbCrLf & "beep" & vbCrLf) & vbCrLf & "beep"   ' change "beep"
    Set DataObject = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}") ' this is a late bound New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObject.SetText Text
    DataObject.PutInClipboard
    Selection(, 2).PasteSpecial ' optional to paste the values next to the selection
End Sub
```

Click on any of the words and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to run the macro.
If you want to select the words or paste the result somewere else, you can remove the first and last optional lines in the macro.

**Update**

The `Transpose` function is limited to 65535 values and will ignore the rest, so here is the alternative:

```vb
Sub beep()
    Range(Selection.End(xlUp), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select ' optional to select the rest of the words
    Selection.Copy
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}") ' this is a late bound New MSForms.DataObject
        .GetFromClipboard
        Text = .GetText
        .Clear
        Text = Replace(Text, vbNewLine, vbNewLine & "beep" & vbNewLine) ' change "beep"
        .SetText Text
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
    Selection(1, 2).PasteSpecial ' optional to paste the values next to the selection
End Sub
```